# How to implement AutoResetEvent with Return Value ability?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, autoresetevent

I need to call WaitOne() at one place of code and call Set() at 2 another places.

It is related with chromiumwebbrowser and I'm making fulfilling of operations synchronously.

Place 1 - where browser operation is called.
Place 2 - where browser status is changed to IsLoading = false.
Place 3 - browsers error event handler, where I know about appearing errors while called opperation is performing. When I found error, I need to throw exception after Wait()

I need to send data about errors from Place 3 to Place 1

All this functionality I implemented in code bellow.

Place 1 receive information from Place 2 and 3 by private _message variable, but inside one class.

I just tryed to find temporary solution but I feel that people already faced with this case before and completed solutions already exists.

Can you:

- give me advises about completed solutions for my perposes
- give me advises for improving of my solution

  public class CustomAutoResetEvent
  {
  int? _waitTimeout = null;

  ```
    public CustomAutoResetEvent(int? waitTimeout = null)
    {
        _waitTimeout = waitTimeout;
    }

    // it is made for considiration of setting from many points
    // if event is setted from one point, another point doesn't change state
    bool _isSetted = false;
    AutoResetEvent _autoResetEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);

    string _message { get; set; } = null;
    public void WaitOneThrow()  // Place 1
    {
        _isSetted = false;
        if (_waitTimeout==null)
            _autoResetEvent.WaitOne();
        else
            _autoResetEvent.WaitOne(_waitTimeout.Value);

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_message))
        {
            string msg = null;
            msg = _message;
            _message = null;

            //if (msg == "ERR_ABORTED")
            //    return;

            throw new Exception(msg);
        }
    }

    public void Set(string errMessage = null) // Place 2, 3
    {
        if (!_isSetted)
        {
             _message = errMessage;
            _autoResetEvent.Set();
            _autoResetEvent.Reset();
            _isSetted=true;
        }
    }
  ```

  }

Comment: You won't find many people with enough enthusiasm for the `AutoResetEvent` class to write an answer. It's an old and low-level technology, that is rarely used in modern development. People usually prefer the [`Task<TResult>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task-1) or other higher level APIs.

Comment: But Task is intended for asynchonous and parallel programming. It decides task of separation of threads.

My issue is about how to stop fulfilling of code and continue it after some event.

What is used for such issues in modern development? I want to discuss it. I showed my code to start this discussion.